# Creating a parameterized method that loops both directions

Tags: loops

I was just looking over the version of 2048 that I wrote, and I realized that I wrote four different methods for moving and merging up, left, down, and right.

Merging left/right and up/down are similar, but one loops 0-3 and the other loops 3-0. Right now I can think of only one way to parameterize this: passing a starting index (3 or 0), incrementer (1 or -1) and end index (0 or 3). This seems like a bad idea. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm sorry, how could I explain better? To me, it seems like the details of the merging and moving are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the same `for` and manage the condition when you actually use the variable.

```
void f(boolean isLeft) {
    int n = 3;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= n ; i++ ) {
        // add here the condition, without a change in for
        if ( isLeft ) {
            // use i
        } else {
            // use n-i
        }
    }
}
```

So, it's enough to pass only **one argument** instead of 3 arguments to that function.

Then:

- if you have left => `isLeft` is `true`

  - `i` will take the following values in this order: 0, 1, 2, 3
- if you have right => `isLeft` is `false`

  - `n-i` will take the following values in this order: 3, 2, 1, 0

Answer (score 0):

Since programming language is not mentioned, I am writing `C` function.

```
void loop(int direction, int length)
{
    // Assuming direction > 0 is left
    int offset = direction > 0 ? 0 : (length - 1);
    int sign = direction > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int index = sign * i + offset;
        //doSomethingOnIndex(index);
    }
}
```

Here `length` is number of iterations. For left use `loop(1, 3);` and for right use `loop(0, 3);`